# How to construct the POE ensemble in julia

Tags: julia

I'm having a trouble in building the POE ensemble in julia. I am following [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2156882?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) paper and part of this other [paper](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~rajnrao/Acta05rmt.pdf).

In julia, I calculate:

```
X = randn(dim, dim)
Q, R = qr(X)
Q = Q*diagm(sign(diag(R)))
ij = (irealiz-1)*dim
phases_ens[1+ij:ij+dim] = angle(eigvals(Q))
```

where `dim` is the matrix dimension and `irealiz` is just and index for the total number of realizations.

I am interested in the phases of Q, since I want that Q be an orthogonal matrix with the appropriate Haar measure. If `dim=50` and the total number of realization is `100000`, and since I am correcting Q, I should expect a flat `phases_ens` distribution. However, I obtain a flat distribution except a peak at zero and at pi. Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Just curious, could you tell us what is the desired "flat" distribution? You mean it should be flat over (-pi,pi] without any "peaks" at 0 and pi?

Comment: Yes, it is between -pi and pi. Looking at the matrix Q, I don't find any preferred "direction" in the cols. of Q. I know that for example, when you diagonalize a comple hermitian matrix numerically, its eigenvectors usually are fixed such that the first entry of each one of them is real. But here, in the orthogonal case, I cannot see, and how to eliminate, the preferred choice.

Comment: Just for the record, I also tried to take the orthogonal matrix from the eigenvector matrix that diagonalizes a GOE; they too suffer from the same flaw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is actually correct, you just have the wrong field

The eigenvalue result is true for unitary matrices (complex entries); based on the code from section 4.6 of the Edelman and Rao paper, if you replace the first line by

```
X = randn(dim, dim) + im*randn(dim, dim)
```

you get the result you want.

Orthogonal matrices (real entries) behave slightly differently (see remark 1, in section 3 of [this paper](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/random_matrices.pdf)):

- when `dims` is odd, one eigenvalue will be +1 or -1 (each with probability 1/2), all others will occur as conjugate pairs.
- when `dims` is even, both +1 and -1 will be eigenvalues with probability 1/2, otherwise there are no real eigenvalues.

(Thanks for the links by the way: I wasn't aware of the Stewart paper)

Comment: Thanks for the remark on the orthogonal matrices. They're always under the rug in common RMT literature and have peculiarities like the eigephases that you mention.